# Xcode 7 / Git - Working with Workspaces

Tags: xcode, git, github

How do you work with Xcode workspaces in git? Until now, I've successfully added several projects to a workspace with each individual project having its own git. Each project then gets pushed to the remote server (github).

Works great, but the problem comes when checking out the entire workspace. I need to check out each project individually, making sure they have the same relative paths as they had on the original computer that made the push. Its tricky and prone to errors.

Is there another way?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to your problem?

Comment: Not sure if its a solution, but what I did was to check out the main project from git, and then from the top menu on Xcode - "Source Control", check out the remaining projects. Note that each of the projects was uploaded to github individually.

Answer (score 1):

Having faced the same problem myself, I used git submodules for the projects I wanted to add them to the main project.

Adding submodules:

```
$git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
$git submodule init
$git submodule update
```

you can update to changes on your remote server:

```
$git submodules update --remote
```

more info [Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)